# PHP Gettext Short Version of <?php not working

Tags: php, xampp, gettext

I'm trying to use gettext to have some internationalization on my companies website. To test the website, I'm using XAMPP. And since I never used gettext before, I'm following this [tutorial](http://pete.akeo.ie/2014/01/using-php-gettext-to-localize-your-web.html):

I'm having problems right from the start. The tutorial is using the short version of `<?php`, which is `<?`.
I can't use the short version, and everthing after that is a mess.
Anybody know what kind of configurations I have to make so it can work?

Comment: Change in php.ini short_tag to on then restart XAMPP server

Comment: Dont use short_tags for the reason mentioned above. Change the code to use `<?php echo $var; ?>` instead. This form will always work while short tags are normally turned off by default. **Make your code usable on any server configuration** Also does you live server have short_tags turned on??

Comment: Probably not, but I tried using the full tags before when I was following the tutorial, and it wasn't working, and when I changed the php.ini file to set the `short_open_tag=ON`, it started working :/

Comment: I say again, Does you LIVE server have short_tags turned on, if not your tests are going to be usless.

Comment: I'll say again, Probably not. That's why I want to use the full tags, but for some reason, it's producing different results than the ones in the tutorial...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Set

```
short_open_tag=On
```

in `php.ini`

And restart your Apache server. For more details please check this [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Answer (score 1):

The PHP Documentation says:

> PHP also allows for short open tag `<?` (which is discouraged since it is only available if enabled using the short_open_tag php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option).
>   -- [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Personally (and seems the docs feels the same) I would recommend you to not use the short tags, especially if you will be running the code on more than one machine (seeing not all machines have this active).

Since PHP 5.4 the `<?= ?>` tags are usable without any ini changes, but the `<?` should still require it.

I suggest using the full `<?php ?>` tags instead, for best compatibility.

Comment: Can you then recommend me a tutorial on how to use GetText that uses the full `<?php ?>` tags?

Comment: Use same tutorial, but change the tags?

Comment: I tried that ofc, but for some reason, it's presenting different results than what the tutorial produces

Comment: If it creates different output, its something other than the tags that is the issue. The `<?` tag is supposed to be the exact same as `<?php`, just shorter. Is it possibly the `<?=` tag that is creating the issue? What is the diff between the expected and the actual result?

Comment: I just found out the problem and it is as you said. The `<?=` is the same as `<?php echo`, and I forgot to change that. Now, the tutorial is becoming quite confusing, So now I'm trying to find a better tutorial.